# With BitBucket can I copy restrictive permissions across branches?

Tags: bitbucket

We are using BitBucket as our source control system.  The main branch (develop) is set as restrictive with a list of people who have exceptions so we have a minimal number of people with merge permissions.  Creating a new branch there is nothing set, is there a way to copy those develop branch permissions over to a new branch to maintain security, rather than manually add them later on?